# Проблема с подключением к удаленному репозиторию

Tags: git, github, git-branch

у меня есть проблема с подключением к удаленному репозиторию github. Есть уже давно функционирующий репозиторий, мне нужно подключиться к нему, создать свою ветку, скопировать другую ветку и изменения занести в свою и начать работать. Но я копирую репозиторий и прописываю следующие команды:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -am 'first commit'
git remote add origin <ссылка репозитория>
```

Но у меня не происходит подключения к к этому репозиторию, я не самый опытный пользователь git, поэтому могу тупить. Если можете помочь напишите ответ, но если вдруг вы не заняты, я буду крайне признателен, если мы созвонимся

Comment: Если он уже есть и давно функционирует, то вам все эти команды не нужны, а нужен git clone

Comment: Я и делаю так, копирую репозиторий, а потом вписываю эти команды

Comment: Вы пишете, что так и делаете, покажите какой командой (или командами). Далее объясните, что значит "не происход подключения". Какие команды при этом исполняете, что ожидаете и что получаете?

Comment: Что во фразе «эти команды не нужны» может быть непонятного?

Comment: На удаленном репозитории я создал ветку. Я хочу скопировать этот репозиторий и перейти на свою ветку. Я ввожу команду git clone <ссылка репозитория>. Копируется репозиторий, но на ветку перейти не могу. Потом ввожу те 4 команды, которые я написал в своем вопросе. Но у меня так и не появляется возможность переключиться на свою ветку, т.е. на скопированном репозитории через консоль я вижу только ветку main

Comment: Для перехода на ветку есть команда git switch. Прочитайте какое-нибудь введение в git

Comment: ну, раз вам сложно изложить то, что вы делаете, в таком виде, чтобы вас поняли окружающие, то выполните, пожалуйста, такую последовательность: 1. создайте новый каталог. 2. сделайте его текущим (`cd путь.к.каталогу`). 3. `$ git clone адрес.хранилища .` (точка в конце важна). 4. приложите к вопросу (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `$ git branch -a`.